# Firestore transaction isn't finding data in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the process of writing a cloud function for my app. I'm using `Firestore` instead of the `RTDB`. For whatever reason, my function is not reading values from the `Firestore` correctly. When it attempts to read values, it reads `undefined`. All i want this function to do is increment the `following_count` value, and I know that it is looking in the right spot because it replaces that value with NaN. How can I change my code so that it reads the Firestore value correctly? Thanks in advance

```
exports.countfollowerschangeFirestore = functions.firestore.document('users/{userid}/following/{followingid}').onWrite(event => {
    const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
    const countRef = collectionRef.parent;
    var new_count;

    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(countRef)
            .then(doc => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    //This is where it is trying to read the data which should be a 0.
                    var new_count = doc.data.following_count + 1;
                    console.log(doc.data.following_count);
                    t.update(countRef, { following_count: new_count });
                }
            });
    }).then(result => {
        console.log('Transaction success!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db.runTransaction()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/Firestore#runTransaction) returns a promise that resolves when the transaction is complete.  You need to return this promise (or its derived promise from the promise chain you're using). from the function to make sure Cloud Functions waits until the work is done.  Otherwise, you may observe unpredictable results.

```
return db.runTransaction(t => { ... }).then(...).catch(...)
```

The other problem in your code is that [doc.data](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentSnapshot#data) is a method call rather than a property, so it should be used like this: `doc.data()`.  Technically, it's also a "snapshot", not a document, so I'd update the name of the variable to that to be more clear.

Comment: I'll give it a go and see what happens

Comment: Nope, doc.data.following_count is still undefined, however that did get rid of a warning I was having!

Comment: Returning that promise is definitely an imperative - missing that can cause problems.  But I guess there is another problem now.

Comment: Yeah I can definitely see how this could cause issues.

Comment: Updated with the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is quite weird because I took that part of the code directly from the Firebase documentation. But my code works now!

Comment: Can you point me to the docs that are incorrect?  I can have them fixed.

Comment: Never mind. Either I'm going crazy and the parentheses weren't there before, or I just completely overlooked them. Either way, it is correct in the documentation. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad to help. :-)